# Symfony3 - create join query of two tables in controller

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.3

How to show two tables data from my controller.

Here is my controller's code.

```
class TestController extends Controller
{
   public function showAction(Request $request)
   {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $teacher = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Teacher::class);

        $query = $em
        ->createQueryBuilder('t')
        ->from('AppBundle:Teacher','t')
        ->Join('AppBundle:Student','s')
        ->where('t.id=id and s.tid=tid')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
    }
}
```

When `print_r` it's showing only one table data.
Please help

Answer (score 2):

Please check below mentioned solution.

```
$query = $em
       ->createQueryBuilder('t.*,s.*')
       ->from('AppBundle:Teacher','t')
       ->Join('AppBundle:Student','s')
       ->where('t.id=id and s.tid=tid')
       ->getQuery()
       ->getResult();
    }
```

Let me know if it not works.

Comment: I don't think that this will work as expected as the first parameter of the `createQueryBuilder()`  method just defines the alias of the entity that should be populated. Please see my answer below for possible solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have defined a relationship between `Teacher` and `Student` in your entities. In this case you can get the `Student` objects by calling `$teacher->getStudents()` (assuming that you have defined such a method in your `Teacher` entity class). See [Doctrine documentation about association mapping](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional)

Example for a One-To-Many relationship:

```
<?php
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/** @Entity */
class Teacher
{
    // ...
    /**
     * One Teacher has Many Students.
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Student", mappedBy="teacher")
     */
    private $students;
    // ...

    public function __construct() {
        $this->students = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}

/** @Entity */
class Student
{
    // ...
    /**
     * Many Students have One Teacher.
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Teacher", inversedBy="students")
     * @JoinColumn(name="teacher_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $teacher;
    // ...
}
```

In the `QueryBuilder` object you can avoid the need of additional queries on `$teacher->getStudents()` calls by adding something like that:

```
$query = $em
   ->createQueryBuilder('t')
   ->from('AppBundle:Teacher','t')
   ->join('AppBundle:Student','s')
   ->select(array('t', 's'))
   ->where('t.id=id and s.tid=tid')
   ->getQuery()
   ->getResult();
}
```

If there is a relationship defined between `Teacher` and `Student` in your entities as mentioned above you can even simplify the join:

```
$query = $em
   ->createQueryBuilder('t')
   ->from('AppBundle:Teacher','t')
   ->join('t.students', 's')
   ->select(array('t', 's'))
   ->getQuery()
   ->getResult();
}
```

Furthmore you do not need to call the `from()` method if you create the `QueryBuilder` object via the `TeacherRepository` object:

```
$query = $teacher
   ->createQueryBuilder('t')
   ->join('t.students', 's')
   ->select(array('t', 's'))
   ->getQuery()
   ->getResult();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = $em
    ->createQueryBuilder('t')
    ->add('select', 't,s')
    ->from('AppBundle:Teacher', 't')
    ->Join('AppBundle:Student', 's')
    ->where('t.id = s.tid')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

it working perfect.

Answer (score 0):

First we select all from Teachers table, then join students. Assume that your relationship name in Teachers model is student. In repository file:

```
public function getWithStudents() {
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('t') 
        ->Join('t.student', 's') 
        ->addSelect('s')
        ->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
}
```

Then in controller call it:

`$teachersWithStudents = $teacher->getWithStudents();`

Or in this case you can just

`$teachersWithStudents = $teacher->getStudents();`

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have two tables.comment table and article table and You want to fetch comments on each article

```
 $commentContent = $em
             // automatically knows to select Comment
            // the "c" is an alias you'll use in the rest of the query
            ->createQueryBuilder('c')
            ->select('c.message, c.name')////Fields required to display
            ->from('AppBundle:Comment','c')
            ->join('AppBundle:Article','a')
            ->where('c.idArticle=a.id and c.publish_mainPage = 1')
            ->orderBy('c.idArticle', 'DESC')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();

 var_dump($commentContent);
```